# Ractive.jsで、押されたボタンをdisabledにするには？

Tags: javascript, ractive.js

Ractive.jsを使用しています。

ボタンのクリックで非同期処理を開始するので、二度押し防止のためにdisabledにしたいのですが、Ractive.jsではどのようにdisabledにするのが王道パターンなのでしょうか？

サンプルHTML

```
<script id="myTemplate" type="text/ractive">
    <button on-click="login">Log in</button>
</script>
```

これに対するJavaScript

```
var ractive = new Ractive({
    el : '#container',
    template : '#myTemplate',
}).on('login', function(e) {
    // ボタンが押された時の処理
    // 押されたボタンをdisabledにしたい
    // idを付けて、$('#loginButton').attr('disabled','disabled');
    // は、何か違う気がする。。。
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ractive.js は Virtual DOM ですので DOM に対する操作は、すべて [`data/ractive.set()`](http://docs.ractivejs.org/latest/ractive-set) 経由でやるのが正しいです。

そのため HTML では、以下のように変数 `processingLogin` を新設して、そのまま `disabled` 属性に繋ぎます。

```
<div id="container"></div>
<script id="myTemplate" type="text/ractive">
    <button on-click="login" disabled="{{processingLogin}}">Log in</button>
</script>
```

JavaScript のほうでは以下のように `login` イベントを受けて、`processingLogin` に対して `set` で `true` を設定するようにします。なお、この例では2秒後に自動的に `false` に戻すようにしました。

```
var ractive = new Ractive({
    el : '#container',
    template : '#myTemplate',
}).on('login', function(e) {
    var r = this;
    this.set('processingLogin', true);
    setTimeout(function() {
        r.set('processingLogin', false);
    }, 2000);
});
```

上記のコードは [How to disable button on Ractive.js](http://jsfiddle.net/koron/brzy59j8/) で試せます。

どうしても DOM 操作を自分でやりたい場合は、このケースでは [`e.node`](http://docs.ractivejs.org/latest/proxy-events#the-event-object) にイベント発生源となった DOM ノードが格納されているので、それを利用すると良いでしょう。またどうしても DOM クエリーを行いたいならば、 jQuery ではなくて [`ractive.find()`](http://docs.ractivejs.org/latest/ractive-find) を使うと、Ractive.js に閉じることができて、より良いと考えられます。